# SQL Query using Join

Tags: sql, join

I have to create a table A which selects few columns from table B and B joins with another table C. But C takes few values as input from another table D. I just want to know the format of the query.

This is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO A
SELECT a,b,c,d
FROM B
LEFT JOIN C
WHERE 1=1, few other conditions
```

I am not sure where should I put D

Comment: Can you elaborate ?  as C takes few values as input from another table D does give any details.

Comment: You are missing an `ON` clause for your `LEFT JOIN`.  But I'm unable to follow your question.  Can you show some sample data and desired result?